Ethical and Unethical methods of developing a game
I am wondering what methods I should and shouldn't do for making a game.
An example of what I am asking is, how do I stop people getting addicted to my game and play for many hours on end?
What ways can I stop people from endlessly grinding for things?
Is there any examples of things I should avoid? What ways should I avoid these things?
Should I actively remove/modify mechanics which are unethical to the game?

The google words for this are called: dark pattern game design

Can we unintentionally make a game that results in long play sessions?
A simple compulsion loop will do it. If you have a fast stimulus-reward cycle, people can play for long sessions. However, since it is a fast cycle, people probably can put the game down at any moment.

Will a simple reward cycle cause the need to come back to the game, or make the players feel like they can't put down the game?
The simple fast loop is repetitive, it will lose novelty quickly and become boring. So to keep the players we introduce novelty at the right time.

Is that bad?
No, this is not a bad thing. What we are talking about is FLOW. Good flow can be meditative, allowing the mind to wander freely while the player goes through the motions of the game.

Can games be bad?
Yes, of course. A game can be bad for the players, for example by exploiting their psychology by leveraging conditioning (including but not limited to the Skinner's Box), fear of missing out, supernormal stimulus, or commitment devices... Usually with the goal of gaining revenue form in-game ads or in-game purchases (without a care if the play sessions will affect their health or schedule, or if they need the money for more pressing matters).
The bottom line is that people who introduce these mechanics often know what they are doing. On that note, please don't put all the blame on developers, sometimes these are pushed by publishers with threat of aborting contracts.
See: Let’s go whaling: Tricks for monetising mobile game players with free-to-play.
Once we understand that the motivation for these designs is lucrative, we also understand that there are other tricks at play, such as anchoring and psycological pricing, marketing mix, etc.
And crypto.

Stopping players from having long sessions
We are talking about ethics... So, should you stop people?
A long play session is not a bad thing per-se. In fact, if it is on the player's own volition, and it does not affect other aspects of their life, it might be a good thing.
It is good that people can enjoy things in their life, and there is no reason why games can't be among those things.
I posit that thinking that you can - or should - manipulate the player into any behavior is the problem. And yes, that includes making them play for a long time, making them watch ads, making them make in-game purchases, etc... But it also includes preventing the player from having a long play session.

Avoiding Grinding
Any game with any mechanic when doing a repetitive action for endless rewards (even if they have diminishing returns) would have to avoid grinding and farming by balance.
For example, you will find that many long lasting MMORPGs start making the experience gained at low levels a breeze, so new players can catch up with the old players who are all at high levels already. Similarly a young MMORPG will want players to not progress too fast so they have time to develop and deploy new content to the game. This is by design.
If you want to make sure it does not happen in your game, by design, avoid such mechanics. Either repetitive actions do not give rewards, or they have a low and clear cap. And pay particular attention to the design of the progression system.

Ethics and game design
It is a good idea to turn "unethical" into something more concrete in order to be useful to stir your design... That way it does not remain a nebulous thing that we are kind of doing but we can't really verify.
Consider: When a game causes some harm to the player due to a long play session - e.g. disrupt their sleep cycle, or make them forget commitments - was it encouraged by your game?
I would argue that if the game is a software that the player has a license to use, you should let them use it.
Thus, do not have a requirment such as "the player should not play longer than x" (which you implement by closing the game on a timer, and then some trickery to stop them from opening it again, which ends bad because the player will learn at what time they can play and they might drop whatever they are doing to play as soon as possible).
Instead have a requirement along the lines of "the game should not encourage the player to play longer than x".
Then, you can start thinking, for example, if the player can kill enemies for health, and killing and enemy takes z seconds, and they need to kill ... wait, that is random chance, that is not good ... let us make it a fixed frequency instead of a random chance, so we know they will fully heal after y enemies taking w time, which is less than x, so that is fine.
But the player can also kill enemies for experience points, and after z experience points they level up, and the next level takes even longer...? And there are how many levels? So maxing up the level would take too much time. Perhaps rethink the progression system. It could be less RPG and more Roguelike or Metroidvania.
I want to reiterate that a game can have experience based progression and still not lead to grinding or farming, which is done by balance. But if you want to avoid the risk, you might look for a different kind of progression system.

Examples
Look at casinos. If any game has been known for addiction, those are the classic casino games. Is there something that behaves similar to a roulette or a slot machine in your game? Don't do that.
Be aware that the extrinsic motivation of a monetary reward plays a role in this. And thus monetization would come to mind. However I remind you that extrinsic motivation does not have to be monetary (for example: a high score or leaderboard).
In my personal opinion, it is better to rely on intrinsic motivation. Although without extrinsic motivation your game might have a smaller audience.

Some games have included timers reminding the players to not play too long.
You can also design your game to have frequent exit points. That has two parts:

Have a good distribution of safe areas (which might also be save points), or avoid long instances where the player can't exit the game without losing progress.
Leave spaces of relative calm in the game, in particular in conjunction with the progress of the narrative.

The idea is that the player would have a sense of progress or accomplishment and a clear indication of when they can safely leave the game. You can think of it as chapters/epìsodes/missions/stages.

Something that I wish more developers did is publish their loot tables and chances (i.e. no hidden chances, and no false promises). This is mostly a matter of transparency, but ultimately it is about letting players make informed decisions, no manipulation and no trickery.

Other ethical concerns
Be aware that ethics in video games have a larger grasp than long play sessions. In particular I want to mention accessibility and monetization. And there is also the case of author rights in user generated content. And let us not forget gatheric player data in general.

Unethical methods of developing a game would be using any kind of labor exploitation, using content without clearing author rights, and similar. Do not do that.

I want to finish - although it is not what you are asking - by pointing out that video games can do a lot of good. They are a communication medium, and are effective for player learning skills and knowledge. In particular, they can be good for learning critical thinking, problem solving, literacy, adaptability, and even communication and collaboration in cooperative multiplayer.
